# How to input this method for calculating cost

Tags: java

I am writing a class for a program where now I need to add a method for coming up with a late fee cost.  This is between movie genre's with each genre costing something different but for the one I will use here will be the Drama genre which has the default late fee (That variable is in a different class, also the dayLate variable is in another class as well)

Anyway what I need to do is make it so that the method adds it up like the number of days late multiplied by the fee.  Right now I have this but I get a compiler error  (Also if it matters, the class with the dayLate variable is not yet finished or compiled)

Anyway here is the Drama class source code

```
class Drama extends Movie
{
    public Drama()
    {
        super();
    }
    public Drama(String rating, int IDnumber, String MovieTitle)
    {
        super(rating, IDnumber, MovieTitle);
    }
    public double CalcLateFees(Fee * dayLate);
}
```

I don't think I did this method correct though.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write your logic in the method's prototype, instead you should receive the values as the parameter and do the logic and return the values like below:

```
public double CalcLateFees(double fee, double dayLate) {

return (fee * dayLate);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I need to do, put the double in front of it although my dayLate is type int (Sorry I didn't show that part)

It's getting late so I'll have to try this tomorrow.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't use pointer just uses reference

So change this

```
public double CalcLateFees(Fee * dayLate);
```

to

```
public double CalcLateFees(Fee  dayLate);
```

Also make sure `Movie` class has default const  and const with `(String rating, int IDnumber, String MovieTitle)` arguments

Comment: I don't think he was trying to use a pointer, but calculating in the signature of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Favor composition over inheritance. Try having a genre property in the movie class. The genre class can hold a fee member.

Answer (score 0):

switch (yourChoice) {

case 1:
Implement your CalclateFees method some how:

```
public double CalcLateFees(Fee dayLate) {
   double fee = 0;
   ....
   return fee;
}
```

case 2:
Declare your CalclateFees method as abstract:

```
public abstract double CalcLateFees(Fee  dayLate);
```

case 3:
Let the Fee class handle the caculation:

```
public double CalcLateFees(Fee  dayLate) {
    return dayLate.calc(this);
}
```

}